# JPanel's size in function of another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I would like to adjust the size of a `JPanel` in function of another panel which contains it.

When I run my code, the panel is tiny and centered on the top of the content panel.

So here's my code :

```
package test;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CodeForStackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
    }
}

class Frame extends JFrame {

    private class Panel extends JPanel {

        private JPanel content = new JPanel();

        Panel() {
            content.setBackground(Color.red);
            this.add(content);
        }

        void adjustSize() {
            this.content.setSize(new Dimension(this.getHeight(), this.getHeight()));
        }
    }

    private Panel contentPane = new Panel();

    Frame() {
        this.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.adjustSize();

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the size yourself, use a LayoutManager.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/.

Comment: `this.content.setSize(new Dimension(this.getHeight(), this.getHeight()));` If the idea is to get a **square** panel, `@Override` the `getPreferredSize()` method. In it, call the `super` method & find the larger value of the width or height, then use that for both. Then heed the advice of @VGR. Layout managers will, at times, ignore the preferred size of a container.